Azure Function App does not show function invocations after switching to new Application Insights instance
I have an Azure Function app that I recently updated to point to a new Application Insights instance.
The new Application Insights instance is configured properly in Settings > Environment variables and it shows up correctly in Settings > Application Insights. Furthermore, if I directly go to the new Application Insights instance, I can see the log output from the Function App functions, so I know it is connected correctly.
However, when I look at my list of functions in the Overview page for the Function App, I am no longer able to see recent invocation details. I see the old ones up to the point that I cut over to my new Application Insights instance, but nothing further.
I double-checked everything in Settings > Environment variables and there is nothing there pointing to the old instance.
I think that somewhere, Function App, or perhaps the portal screen itself, is still connected to my old Application Insights instance. When I look at Overview > Properties, it does indeed name the old Application Insights instance. But I can't see anywhere where I can actually change this. (Again, within Settings > Application Insights, it is pointed to the new, correct instance.)
How can I fix this?

Okay, I got it fixed. Here's what I did:

Delete the old Application Insights instance.
Within the Function App, go to Overview > Properties. (This is where it previously showed the old instance of Application Insights.)
Under Application Insights, where it previously showed the name of the old instance, it now gives you link to connect to a new instance.
Click the link and go through the wizard to connect to a new instance, just selecting the instance you are already connected to. This didn't create any new Environment variable records for me, but it must have jogged some other background configuration setting that I can't see, because now I can see my function invocations again from within the Function App.

I hope this helps someone!

I was having this problem after updating our app to .net 8, isolated. Tried all the things (program.cs configuration, host.json). Tried deleting old appinsights, created a new log analytics workspace, new app insights, connected it to functions app, still no love. Turns out setting Host.Results log level to Information was the fix. I swear I had tried this (or at least at trace) and not seen it work, but there it is.
